# Robots building a bridge anime

Tags: story-identification, anime

Could someone please help me identify this anime?  A few years ago, I remember watching an anime short? about some robots building a bridge autonomously.  A man is sent out to investigate why the bridge hasn't been completed.  I think I remember the name being something along the lines of: The delay/construction of bridge (Japanese name).

What type of anime was it?
I think it was a just a one time feature film.

Where did you watch it?
Youtube.

What was the year of production?
Not sure, but I think it was late 90's or early 2000's.

What's the genre?
Sci-Fi, robots building a bridge with an AI capable of talking and understanding a human as well as other high level reasoning.

Setting?
Futureish, it seemed like it would be not too far in the future since the machines were all completely autonomous.

Key spoiler points I remember:

> The "foreman" robot was malfunctioning badly, and would send machines to do work they were not designed for, but claimed it would be more efficient.  It also would bring the man food, however it started to slowly put non-edible items in the food.  At the end, the inspector is locked in his room for delaying the robot from doing its job.

Thanks.

Edit:
Was it only robots? Was it mechas (giant robots piloted by humans)? Was there humans? These were not Mecha style robots, and there was, (from what I remember) only one human in the movie.  There may have been some at the very beginning and end, but pretty much only one human.  One foreman robot and a number of labor robots.

How big? How did they look? 
The foreman was a humanoid robot, in both size and general shape.  The rest were the size of the machinery that they represented, so bulldozer size or thereabouts.

> Another point I kinda remember is that others were sent to investigate the bridge, but hadn't made it back.  Some of them left clues as to what was going on, but the foreman didn't/couldn't read them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Neo Tokyo*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185481/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), a 1987 movie.

It is composed of 3 stories, and the one you saw is the last one, 
*Construction Cancellation Order*:

> A revolution in the fictional South American country of the Aloana Republic has resulted in a new government being installed; this new government refuses to accept a contract detailing the construction of Facility 444. The company responsible for the construction has begun to lose millions, so salaryman Tsutomu Sugioka (Yū Mizushima/Robert Axelrod) is sent to stop production. The work is completely automated, carried out by robots programmed to finish the job no matter the consequences and led by a robot identified as 444-1 (Hiroshi Ōtake/Jeff Winkless). Witnessing the destruction of several robots and Robot 444-1's refusal to cease operations, Tsutomu begins to lose his patience and is nearly killed by 444-1 who was programmed to eliminate anything that poses a threat to the project. He retaliates by destroying 444-1 and follows its powercord that leads to the energy source of the robots in an attempt to finally end the production. Unknown to Tsutomu, the old government has been restored and they have agreed to honor the contract once more.
>
> <sub>source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_Tokyo_(film))</sub>

Comment: That's it, and explains why I can't find it on its own, it's part of a movie.  Also, that explains why Youtube doesn't have it anymore as well.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help,  it took a while since I looked from 1990-to-2015, but then went back and found this,  I was about to leave it but saw that it was by parts and the last story was somewhat similar and the title was also similar to the one you wrote.

Comment: I used gogoanime filter.  neo tokyo sub - 1. Labyrinth Labyrinthos
A girl and her cat fall through a looking-glass into a dark labyrinth full of strange people.

2. Running Man
In the distant future, a tough racer uses his psychokinetic powers against his opponents during his final race. 

3. The Order to Stop Construction
A snooty salaryman is sent by his bosses to the jungle to stop a completely automated construction job, and spends several days there arguing with the robots.